# Add a new row in table when on the last cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code. I need to do this for DY1 to Dy30. This will be a lot of code and very lengthy. How do I make it compact and short?

Also I want to add new row to the table in Active Sheet when executing the last IF Statement.

```
Option Explicit
Sub send()

Dim val As String
Dim j As Integer

val = Sheets("Form").Range("C8").Value

'-------FORDY1-----------

If val = "DY1" Then
For j = 2 To 9

Sheets("Form").Cells(j, 3).Copy

If j = 2 Then
Sheets("1").Select
Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Else

If j = 3 Then
Sheets("1").Select
Range("B" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Else

If j = 4 Then
Sheets("1").Select
Range("C" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Else

If j = 5 Then
Sheets("1").Select
Range("D" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Else

If j = 6 Then
Sheets("1").Select
Range("E" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Else

If j = 7 Then
Sheets("1").Select
Range("F" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Else

If j = 8 Then
Sheets("1").Select
Range("G" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Else

If j = 9 Then
Sheets("1").Select
Range("H" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Table.ListRows.Add 'Trying to add new row or send "Tab" key which normally get's down on next row of table
Else
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
Next j
Else
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Also I need to do this for DY1 to Dy30 this will be a lot of code and very lengthy Can anyone let me know how to make it short.

Comment: You haven't given any indication on what to do with DY2 -> DY30.

Comment: This was for DY1 same goes for DY2 to DY30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks shorter.

```
Sub send()
    If Sheets("Form").Range("C8").Value = "DY1" Then
        Sheets("1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 8) = _
            Application.Transpose(Sheets("Form").Cells(2, 3).Resize(8, 1).value)
    End If
End Sub
```

If the value in the **Form** worksheet's C8 cell is equal to **DY1** then take the values from C2:C9 and [TRANSPOSE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027) then (i.e. flip rows into columns) and put them into the **1** worksheet's first blank row in columns A:H.

Comment: Yes it's right way to do this I have just started with VBA so no idea about transpose, offset,Resize and other functions.